# How to destructure a composable?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am having trouble destructuring refs from a Vue 3 composable using TypeScript.

In the examples below I am trying to destructure `document` and `error` refs from a `getDocument` composable.

**FIRST ATTEMPT:**

In this first attempt I tried to give the `document` ref a very general Type using an Index Signature of `{ [key: string]: string | undefined }`. I thought this would permit me to return any shape of document without errors. Spolier: I was wrong, it produces many errors in the Vue template.

This is the Vue 3 SFC:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="document">
    <img :src="document.coverUrl" />
    <div v-if="!document.songs.length">No songs</div> //Error #1 detailed below
    <div v-for="song in document.songs" :key="song.id">{{ song.title }}</div> //Errors #2, #3, and #4 detailed below
    <div v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import getDocument from "@/composables/getDocument";
const { error, document } = getDocument("9Tn765FhtBa2");
</script>
```

This is the `getDocument` composable (an abridged version with Pseduo code):

```
import { ref, Ref } from "vue";

const getDocument = (
  docId: string
): {
  document: Ref<{ [key: string]: string | undefined } | null>;
  error: Ref<string | null>;
} => {
  const document = ref<{ [key: string]: string | undefined } | null>(null);
  const error = ref<string | null>(null);

  const docFromDatabase = getdocFromDatabase(docId);
  document.value = {
    ...docFromDatabase.data(),
    id: docFromDatabase.id,
  };
  error.value = "Some error text here";

  return { document, error };
};

export default getDocument;
```

During this attempt it produced many errors in the template of the Vue SFC:

1. The `v-if="!document.songs.length"` has an error of `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`
2. The `v-for="song in document.songs"` has an error of `The right-hand side of a 'for...in' statement must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter, but here has type 'string'.ts(2407)`
3. The `:key="song.id"` has an error of `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)`
4. The `{{ song.title }}` has an error of `Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)`

**SECOND ATTEMPT:**

In this second attempt I tried creating and passing a `Playlist` interface to the composable function as a generic Type. This solved all the SFC template errors, but created a different error inside the composable:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="document">
    <img :src="document.coverUrl" />
    <div v-if="!document.songs.length">No songs</div>
    <div v-for="song in document.songs" :key="song.id">{{ song.title }}</div>
    <div v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import getDocument from "@/composables/getDocument";
interface Playlist {
  coverUrl: string;
  createdAt: string;
  description: string;
  filePath: string;
  songs: { [key: string]: string | number }[];
  title: string;
  userId: string;
  userName: string;
  id: string;
}
const { error, document } = getDocument<Playlist>("9Tn765FhtBa2");
</script>
```

This is the new `getDocument` composable:

```
import { ref, Ref } from "vue";

const getDocument = <T>(
  docId: string
): {
  document: Ref<T | null>;
  error: Ref<string | null>;
} => {
  const document = ref<T | null>(null);
  const error = ref<string | null>(null);

  const docFromDatabase = getdocFromDatabase(docId);
  document.value = {
    ...docFromDatabase.data(),
    id: docFromDatabase.id,
  };
  error.value = "Some error text here";

  return { document, error }; // Error on "document" is detailed below
};

export default getDocument;
```

This solved all the errors in the SFC. But now the composable has a very complex error at the bottom on the returned `document` ref:

```
Type 'Ref<UnwrapRef<T> | null>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<T | null>'.
  Type 'UnwrapRef<T> | null' is not assignable to type 'T | null'.
    Type 'UnwrapRef<T>' is not assignable to type 'T | null'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T | null'.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
          'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.ts(2322)
getDocumentT.ts(6, 3): The expected type comes from property 'document' which is declared here on type '{ document: Ref<T | null>; error: Ref<string | null>; }'
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be an `id` and `title` property on each song, or on the document itself?

Comment: Each song in the songs array has an `id`, `title`, and `artist`. So I used to Index Signature of `{ [key: string]: string | number }` to cover all those things, plus others that might be added later. The document itself also has an `id` and a `title`.

Comment: I would recommend then adding those properties. `{id: string, title: string, artist: string, [key: string]: string | number}[]`. That way, TS knows exactly what is on each song variable.

Comment: @2pichar Ok have tried adding that, but unfortunatley it doesn't change any of the errors. Still having the same problem with destructuring refs from a composable.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous answer, don't specify return types, unless you really need to, let them be inferred from what you return. The problem is that it won't be `Ref<T | null>` for any T, because it will behave differently if T is already a ref (this is why UnwrapRef appears). If T is more specific, make it so, you'll likely avoid these problems. The first problem is that document isn't really null, it's instantly assigned with `document.value =`. The second problem is that T is efficiently a specific object with `id` property, not just any type. Use  `T extends` where possible.

Comment: Thanks again @EstusFlask, your input is helping me learn a lot! I also found another solution of `const document = ref(null) as Ref<T | null>;` which seems to work with the return type. I learned more about `T extends` and played around with it a bit, but I couldn't figure out how it would help in this scenario. If you have more details about that I would love to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions.

**First Solution**

As mentioned by @EstusFlask in the comments, I could just remove the return type.

In that case the composable beomes:

```
import { ref } from "vue";

const getDocument = <T>(docId: string) => {
  const document = ref<T | null>(null);
  const error = ref<string | null>(null);

  const docFromDatabase = getdocFromDatabase(docId);

  document.value = {
    ...docFromDatabase.data(),
    id: docFromDatabase.id,
  };

  error.value = "Some error text here";

  return { document, error };
};

export default getDocument;
```

**Second Solution**

The other way I found is to keep the return type, but use `const document = ref(null) as Ref<T | null>;` to cast `document` as `Ref<T | null>`.

This also removes the error on `document` and has the added bonus of satisfying ESLint which complains when there is no return type on complex functions.

```
import { ref, Ref } from "vue";

const getDocument = <T>(
  docId: string
): {
  document: Ref<T | null>;
  error: Ref<string | null>;
} => {
  const document = ref(null) as Ref<T | null>;
  const error = ref<string | null>(null);

  const docFromDatabase = getdocFromDatabase(docId);

  document.value = {
    ...docFromDatabase.data(),
    id: docFromDatabase.id,
  };

  error.value = "Some error text here";

  return { document, error };
};

export default getDocument;
```